# Simple Hash that is always equal between C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, hash

I have a C# WebService and a (Java) Android Application. Is there a SIMPLE hash function that produces the same result between these two languages? The simplest C# hash is a String.GetHashCode(), but I can't replicate it in Java. The simplest Java hash is not simple at all. And I don't know if I can replicate it exactly in C#.

In case it's relevant, I'm hashing passwords before sending it across the internet. I'm currently using Encode64, but that's obviously not secure since we can reverse it.

---

EDIT: Ok, I settled on using SHA256. Incase somebody else needs a quick solution, here are the code that I used, considering that I wanted both the C# and the Java to output the exact same string and I needed the simplest possible solution.

**Java**

```
public String Hash(String s)
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(s.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                    .substring(1));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**C#**

```
public static string Hash(String s)
{
    HashAlgorithm Hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] strBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    byte[] strHash = Hasher.ComputeHash(strBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(strHash).Replace("-","").ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
}
```

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: How about hashing the String with common hash function from some library/existing package?

Comment: AES. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Make sure you don't just send the plain hash over the internet. That's no better than sending the password in plaintext, since someone can simply capture and replay the hash transmission to log in.

Comment: I KNEW I shouldn't have used the word "secure".. I'm actually securing my customer's passwords against my own employees, not against hackers..

Comment: I'd argue that the simplest string hash in Java is also `String.hashCode()` and just by looking at the two, I'd say the Java version is simpler than the C# one. The standard way to calculate hash codes in Java is as simple as taking some prime (usually 31) and then putting the values of an object together as the `String.hashCode()` describes: `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]` - should be really easy to replicate in C#. However, since you're sending passwords through a network, I second the recommendations of using some SHA implementation instead.

Comment: i am facing similar problem, but i can't change my java code, it is the legacy one and all i can do it just change c# code somehow to match the hash generated by Java. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the kind of hashes implemented by `String.GetHashCode()` and `String.hashCode()` are not designed to be used for this kind of thing.  For a start, they only hash to a 32 but number (at least in the Java case), so there is a significant risk of collisions.  In this case, if two different passwords map to the same hash ... then someone has a chance of 1 in 2^32 that a randomly chosen password will be accepted.  (And the flip side is that if the bad guy can intercept the 32 bit hash for a valid password, they have a big "leg up" in guessing what the original password was!)

Second, sending a crypto hash (such as produced by MD5, SHA-256, etc), is probably not going to solve your security problems ... unless you send the hash over SSL or something.  Sure, the bad guy won't be able to recover the original password was, but they CAN intercept and use the hash in a "replay" attack.  (There are ways to combat this, but they either require a shared secret key, or use of public/private key encryption ... and you HAVE TO know what you are doing if you want this to be secure.)

In short, you need to discuss your whole problem and proposed solution(s) with someone who has solid security expertise.

---

If you really think that this is not a security issue, then an MD5 hash should be fine.  But don't say that you weren't warned ...

(But don't use a simple 32-bit hashcode because that is barely more secure than base64.)

Comment: Ok, first off, I'm not programming a nuclear reactor (eg. I /dont/ have a security problem). I'm asking for a SIMPLE hash since security is not a concern. I just don't want my own employees scripting a Decode64 across the PasswordHash field of the DB and finding out that most people use the same password with their other accounts. If someone uses a replay attack on my service, I'll be very flattered that they even bothered.

Comment: Dealing with passwords requires good encryption. Your employees will recycle passwords and its your responsiblity to look after them correctly. You may not have a security problem now, but you will eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Use a standard algorithm such as MD5 or SHA256, which will produce the same results on any platform (if implemented correctly), but you might want to think about if this is truly the best way to "encrypt" a password before you send it across the wire.

Comment: I have a very big chance of running into something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095664/c-sharp-sha-256-vs-java-sha-256-different-results and I just don't have the time to debug. Which is why I'm looking for a SIMPLE hash..

Comment: I'm curious why you think you have a big chance of doing so? The accepted answer to that question is a simple fix - make sure you are explicit about which encoding you use when converting from a String to a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try encryption if you're looking for security. Otherwise, there a built in hashing algorithms such as MD5. This should be reliably consistent between the 2

Comment: +1. MD5 is wayyyyy better than base64 :). But yes SHA-256 would be better (SHA-256 in C# and Java - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095664/c-sharp-sha-256-vs-java-sha-256-different-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in Java it can match that of C#

```
public static String getEncryptedPassword(String clearTextPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(clearTextPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    String hex = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, digest));
    String st = new String(hex.toUpperCase());
    for (int i = 2; i < (hex.length() + hex.length() / 2) - 1 ;) {
        st = new StringBuffer(st).insert(i, "-").toString();
            i = i + 3;        
    }
    return st ; 

}
```